# How to bold selected text using PDFKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I want to only bold the selected text on PDF file using PDFKit in Swift.

I tried to solve this issue with annotation but couldn't.

Here is my code:

```
let selections = pdfView.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()
guard let page = selections?.first?.pages.first else { return }

selections?.forEach({ selection in
   let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .freeText, withProperties: nil)
   highlight.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
   page.addAnnotation(highlight)
})
pdfView.document?.write(toFile: "path to save the changes")
```

What should I do now? Or should I use an another method not annotation?

If someone can support me with this, let me know.

Also, please share me the source code if possible.

Thanks for your time!